# How can I move a file in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

When moving a file in Google Drive, is there any way to move a file other than drag and drop or using the tiny "move to" window (see screenshot below)?

[image]

I do not want to install any client on my computer.

Comment: "More convenient" in what way?

Comment: @AʟE. ok I have removed the word.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid without a local client those *are* your two options for moving files.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Manually create a Favorites folder and populate it with your most frequent used folders by using the **add-to** keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> .

## Explanation

Create a Favorites folder and to make it appear at the top use a character that will make it appear on top. If you use `[A-Za-z]` characters to name your files and folders you could use `_` (underscore) or any other similar character.

To make that your folder stands out, assign a bright color like blue, red, etc.

Once you have created you Favorites folder, then you could move your files and folders as usual but now you don't require to follow the whole path to find the most frequently used folders or those that you require during your "clean-up" project.

[image: My Drive > _Favorites]

[image: Move to drop down]

## References

[Add the Same File to Multiple Folders in Google Drive without Copying](http://www.labnol.org/internet/add-files-multiple-drive-folders/28715/)

Answer (score -1):

## Short answer

Besides the mentioned methods in the question you could use [Google Apps Script](http://www.google.com/script/start).

## Extended answer

Google Drive files as well as other Google web applications items (calendars, events, email messages, contacts, etc.) could be handled through Google Apps Scripts or by the more "convenient" "add-ons" or user / third-party web apps.

At this time I don't know about an existing add-on / web-app other than [AODOCS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aodocs-smartbar-for-googl/aikbehojjdffmangolfbohjdigfdnepa) that is for G Suite accounts and should be enabled by the G Suite administrator of each organization.

### General Hints

File and Folder class in the DriveApp Service doesn't have a move method but there are a add and remove methods.

Your script should have a way to specify the file/folder and the destination folder. For a simple script, get the file ID from the file/folder URL.

## Reference

[Move Files to Another Folder with Google Scripts](https://ctrlq.org/code/19975-move-file-between-folders)